# Пакетная установка плагинов в Sublime

Tags: sublime-text

Переустановил операционку и настраиваю плагины на `Sublime`, но устанавливать их по одному очень долго и муторно.

Подскажите, можно ли как-нибудь добавлять плагины в `Sublime` "пачкой" за раз?

Comment: Про закрытие: считаю, что вопрос по теме, т.к. это один из популярных инструментов программиста. И к [настройке сложного ПО](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/719/181472) тоже можно отнести. И даже метка у него есть своя, вполне популярная. Т.е. это вопрос вида "Как сделать X в IDE Y?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Используйте [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3);
2. Команда `Advanced Install Package` принимает список пакетов через запятую "пачкой".

[А вообще](https://github.com/mrmartineau/SublimeTextSetupWiki/issues/3) с Package Control достаточно просто подложить нужный файлик (`./Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-settings`). Этот файл заполняется самим Sublime при установке новых пакетов. При переустановке ОС целесообразно сделать его резервную копию, чтобы после использовать ее для быстрой установки.

`Package Control.sublime-settings` содержит список вида:

```
{
        "installed_packages":
        [
                "ApacheConf.tmLanguage",
                "Package Control",
                "SublimeLinter"
        ]
}
```

при запуске все отсутствующие должны выкачаться и установиться.

> To install Package Control,
>   http://sublime.wbond.net/Package%20Control.sublime-package needs to be
>   placed inside of the Installed Packages/ folder. The next time Sublime
>   starts, it will install the package.
>
> To batch install other packages, a Package Control.sublime-settings
>   file needs to be placed into the Packages/User/ folder. Inside of the
>   settings file should be a JSON object with the key
>   "installed_packages" that references a list of package names. When
>   Package Control starts, if any of those packages are not present, the
>   will be automatically downloaded and installed. Here is an example:
>   http://pastebin.com/NLEavL1K.

Comment: Верно ли я понял, что перед переустановкой нужно просто сделать бэкап файла `Package Control.sublime-settings`? Или его нужно руками написать?

Comment: я так понял что можно и так и так)) главное результат - есть файл из содержимым будут и плагины

Comment: @NickVolynkin достаточно сделать бэкап конечно.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: дополнил. Проверьте пожалуйста, верно ли.