# Предпросмотр правок без внесения изменений в Википедию или другой вики-сайт при их редактировании посредством Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Здравствуйте. Википедию и прочие сайты с вики-разметкой удобно править при помощи плагина [Mediawiker](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker) редактора Sublime Text 3. Проблема — отсутствие предпросмотра правок. Нашёл плагин [OmniMarkupPreviewer](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer), вроде бы разрешающий проблему, но не получается его запустить. Когда нажимаю на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, в браузере открывается страница со следующей ошибкой:

[image: Error 404 OmniMarkupPreviewer]

Произвёл изменения в <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> → <kbd>OmniMarkupPreviewer</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd>, как указано [здесь](https://github.com/timonwong/OmniMarkupPreviewer/issues/82#issuecomment-158705946):

```
{
    "server_host": "0.0.0.0",
    "server_port": 9998
}
```

Да только вместо старой ошибки появилась новая:

```
Error: 404 Not Found

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9998/view/52' caused an error:

'buffer_id(52) is not valid (closed or unsupported file format)'

**NOTE:** If you run multiple instances of Sublime Text, you may want to adjust
the `server_port` option in order to get this plugin work again.
```

В консоли (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) выводится:

```
OmniMarkupPreviewer: [INFO] Launching web browser for http://127.0.0.1:51004/view/96
OmniMarkupPreviewer: [ERROR] Exception occured while rendering using MediaWikiRenderer
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin.USER-AC59577756\Application Data\Sublime Text 3\Packages\OmniMarkupPreviewer\OmniMarkupLib\RendererManager.py", line 266, in render_text
    rendered_text = renderer.render(text, filename=filename)
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin.USER-AC59577756\Application Data\Sublime Text 3\Packages\OmniMarkupPreviewer\OmniMarkupLib\Renderers\base_renderer.py", line 77, in render
    text = self.executable_check(text, kwargs['filename'])
    File "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin.USER-AC59577756\Application Data\Sublime Text 3\Packages\OmniMarkupPreviewer\OmniMarkupLib\Renderers\base_renderer.py", line 106, in executable_check
    startupinfo=self.get_startupinfo())
    File "./subprocess.py", line 824, in __init__
    File "./subprocess.py", line 1118, in _execute_child
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
```

Хотя при помощи этого же плагина доступен прямой предпросмотр Markdown текстов без перезагрузки и сохранения страницы и расширений для автообновления страницы — вроде [Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) — в браузере.

[image: Пример Markdown в OmniMarkupPreviewer]

Что я должен сделать для превью внесённых мной изменений, не сохраняя каждый раз правки на вики-сайте? Спасибо.

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском не является багтрекером программы Sublime Text. Описанный случай использования также не относится к программированию. Используйте почту или форум поддержки Sublime Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вчера, 20 апреля 2016, появилась возможность предпросмотра страниц прямо через Mediawiker путём запросов к API сайта на движке MediaWiki с преобразованием вики-страницы в html.

1. Устанавливаем плагин Mediawiker через [Package Control](http://forum.sublimetext.ru/index.php?topic=6.0). В данной инструкции не разбираются все его функции, читаем на GitHub [описание](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker), [инструкции и настройки](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker/wiki).
2. По умолчанию доступно редактирование для Английской, Русской Википедий, и [сайта движка](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). Если мы работаем с другими сайтами, то <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Paskage Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Mediawiker</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd> → между `{}` вводим их в следующем формате:

   ```
   "mediawiki_site":  
       {
         "Циклопедия": { "host": "cyclowiki.org", "path": "/w/", "pagepath": "/wiki/", "username": "Саша_Черных", "password": "MyPassword", "domain": "" },    
         "Традиция": { "host": "traditio.wiki", "path": "/w/", "pagepath": "/wiki/", "username": "Саша_Черных", "password": "MyPassword", "domain": "" },
       },
   ```
3. Проводим биндинг горячих клавиш, при нажатии которых в браузере откроется редактируемая страница: <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Paskage Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Mediawiker</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - User</kbd> → между `[]` вписываем код:

   ```
   // Предпросмотр вики-страницы в Медиавикере
   { "keys": ["Ctrl+7", "Ctrl+p"], "command": "mediawiker_preview" },
   ```

   Как видно из кода, предпросмотру соответствует команда `"mediawiker_preview"`. Чтобы настроить горячие клавиши на другие команды, которыми вы собираетесь пользоваться, установив плагин [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer), узнаём соответствие команд функциям Mediawiker'а: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → <kbd>PackageResourseViewer:Open Resourse</kbd> (благодаря [fuzzy поиску](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147856/) достаточно набрать просто `prvor`) → <kbd>Mediawiker</kbd> → <kbd>Mediawiker.sublime-commands</kbd>.

   Чтобы сочетание наверняка не оказалось ничем не занятым, я выбираю двухэтапные хоткеи — то есть ввожу <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>, затем <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, и только после двух нажатий выполняется необходимая команда. Можете назначить одноэтапный, только лучше удостоверьтесь, что шорткат свободен: <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - Default</kbd> → в открывшемся файле <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> → временно отключаем кнопку <kbd>Regular expression</kbd>, иначе не удастся найти символ `+`, → вводим в форму поиска сочетание клавиш, которое хотим использовать, → если оно задействовано, выбираем другое, которое, впрочем, также может быть занято каким-то из установленных вами плагинов.
4. Выбираем сайт, статьи и прочие страницы которого собираемся редактировать: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> → <kbd>Select wiki</kbd> (не забываем о fuzzy поиске):

   [image: Выбор сайта в верхней консоли Sublime Text]
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> → вводим название страницы, которую намереваемся править, → она откроется в новой вкладке → редактируем страницу.
6. Жмём хоткей, который мы задали на третьем этапе, когда захотим просмотреть, как выглядят внесённые изменения, → в браузере откроется новая вкладка. Клавиши быстрого доступа придётся нажимать для каждого случая превью, при этом всегда будет открываться новая вкладка (если что, в Windows активная вкладка закрывается сочетанием <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>). По [словам разработчика](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker/issues/62#issuecomment-212965251) синхронный предпросмотр, как в Markdown (см. гифку в вопросе), не будет реализован из-за получающегося при этом DDOS'а вики-сайта.

   Результат:

   [image: На прицеле ваш мозг]
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> → вводим описание правки → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Изменения внесены на вики-сайт.

Функция пока (на 21 апреля 2016) находится в стадии <sup>beta</sup>, о багах [сообщаем разработчику](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker/issues).

Comment: вы уверены, что каждая новая одного из вики движков доступна отдельного упоминания на ruSO?

Comment: @PashaPash, [**1**] — «новая» что? // [**2**] — решение для движка MediaWiki, стоящего на подавляющем числе вики-сайтов, включая Википедию, не сказал бы «одного из» // [**3**] — взгляните на дату вопроса. я его писал не с целью рассказать о новой функции, а в надежде получить ответ. // Спасибо.

Comment: @PashaPash, могу также получить пояснения, чем, собственно, плохи для базы знаний SO вопросы вида «Как сделать X в IDE Y?», если решение заключается в новой функции Y? О допустимости подобных вопросов в общем см. [комментарий Nick Volynkin](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437702/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-sublime#comment457584_437702), ни здесь ни на EnSO вопросы по настройке Sublime Text не закрываются.

Comment: @PashaPash, если какие-то из моих ответов не соответствуют правилам Stack Overflow,  дайте знать, и я удалю их. Только исходный код, пожалуйста, позвольте сохранить, дабы я мог разместить удалённые сообщения в своём блоге. Спасибо.

Comment: Вопросы по настройке использованию sublime text в качестве инструмента разработчика, IDE - это на грани онтопика. Настройка и использование sublime text для редактирования вики - я бы сказал что это уже оффтопик. По сути, это ничем не отличается от вопросов по пользованию Word-ом. Это обсуждалось [на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2755) с [последующим голосованием](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/2776/177221) и результато вроде как "против".

Comment: @PashaPash, я видел все вопросы по Sublime Text на русском SO и многие на английском — ни один вопрос по применению редактора не в качестве инструмента разработчика не закрыли, на основании чего безбоязненно писал тут подобные мануалы. Ваше право, конечно, однако **[1]** Полагаю, что придётся закрывать очень много, // **[2]** Не думаю, что жёсткая трактовка правил сыграет на пользу базе знаний SO. // Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512