# Как узнать точный размер физического диска?

Tags: windows, диск

Как узнать размер физического диска (не раздела!) в Windows 7 с точностью до байта?

Управление компьютером -> Управление дисками показывает значение в ГБ.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245436 проще говоря попробуй в cmd выполнить `chkdsk`

Comment: @Invision 1. Это что-то старое. 2. Мне не нужен размер кластера, мне нужен размер физического диска. 3. chkdsk не работает с физическими дисками, только с разделами.

Comment: Как ты это хочешь сделать? Программно?

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, желательно не программно. Но можно и программно.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384916

Comment: Qwertiy, где я могу почитать о грани между допустимыми и нет вопросами по администрированию на Stack Overflow? Некоторые Ваши вопросы, как этот, лично мне представляются не соответствующими тематике сайта. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, думаю, нигде. И вообще, нормальные вопросы же.

Comment: Qwertiy, модераторы [принялись за закрытие](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503052/199934) моих вопросов. Если Ваш вопрос таки не соответствует тематике Stack Overflow на русском, у них есть все основания прийти и по Вашу душу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной программой "Сведения о системе". 
Пуск - Выполнить - `msinfo32` 
Раздел "Компоненты - Запоминающие устройства - Диски"
[image: Информаия о диске]

Answer (score 3):

Не нашёл как сделать это через `powershell` или `wmic`, но есть windows-версия пакета [S.M.A.R.T. Monitoring Tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/files/smartmontools/). Синтаксис такой же, как и в `linux`, т.е. для первого жёсткого диска надо ввести `smartctl --all /dev/sda`.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Останется только отпарсить строку `User Capacity`.

Comment: Как это wmic не поможет? а как же простой запрос `wmic diskdrive get size,status,model`

Comment: Не знаток wmi. Искал в гугле и яндексе - они не подсказали.

Comment: @LamerXaKer, да, работает.